# Project made of several projects

Tags: android, gradle, merge, architecture

Can someone enlighten me, I have spent a lot of time on this and I am starting to doubt if it is actually possible, and if so, how.

I have two Android application projects **with nested libraries**, and I would like to have a parent project that would reference both such as:

**ParentProject**

```
-app/src
```

**-ProjectA**

```
 -app/src  
 -lib1   
 -lib2
```

**-ProjectB**

```
 -app/src  
 -lib3   
 -lib4
```

So I can use classes from project A and B inside the ParentProject while keeping them separate.

I am using Android Studio / Gradle

Thank you

Update

I had trouble because of the application I was trying to use, I haven't figured out why yet. But if you do the following steps, you should be able to use any other project in you current one:

In your subproject's build.gradle:

- Change apply plugin: 'com.android.application' to apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
- Remove the applicationId tag
- Add subproject to your parent project build path
- Add subproject path to your settings.gradle in the form

```
include ':subproject'
project(':subproject').projectDir = new File('../subproject')
```

- Add dependency to the subproject by adding the following to your project's build.gradle:

```
compile project(':some-library')
```

Credit to @yosriz for helping out.

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

In your **settings.gradle** define the library project/s and the path (preferably relative) that you are trying to include in the main project.

```
include ':some-library'
project(':some-library').projectDir = new File('..\\some-library')
```

next, in your build.gradle of the app include the dependency to the imported library:

```
compile project(':some-library')
```

Comment: Hi yosriz, I'm resolving issue after issue, I think it's because of nested libraries, see edits

Comment: @Tom, as explained in my answer, you can reference to the library with relative/absolute path, so you can link to a library from a different project by using its path. more recommended way, is to extract shared libraries from withing a project, and than reference it inside the projects that using it.

Answer (score 0):

- Add ProjectA and ProjectB in your ParentProject Root Directory then--
  update settings.gradle by

  include ':ProjectA', ':ProjectB'

  include ':ParentProject'

  Then add these lines in your ParentProject build.gradle file
  compile project(':ProjectA')  compile project(':ProjectB')

  Finally press sync button.

Comment: Hi AndroidAnDandroid, same as other response, I'm resolving issue after issue, I think it's because of nested libraries, see edits